# Problems accessing calendar (privacy setting) in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ios6, privacy

I've just published an update for my iPhone app, which shall support iPhone 5 dimensions, and also is the first update having iOS 6 as base SDK. Right after the update, quite a few users contacted me, complaining that the app is unable to use calendars of the device. Also they say, my app does not appear under the privacy settings of iOS6, thus, calendar access cannot be enabled.

I was not aware of this privacy feature when submitting the update, so I did not have a look at the SDK and if I need to adjust my app towards those privacy features of iOS 6. 
So the question is:

a) do I have to make any modifications to my app so the calendar access is working?
b) is there any workaround for the current (not working) situation so users can access calendars?

The curious thing is: I have iOS 6 on my iPad, and I freshly installed my (iPhone-)app. Not only does it appear in the privacy settings (where I can enable/disable calendar access for my app) but I can also access any calendars from within the app without any problems.

As I do not have an iPhone 5, I don't know if this particular device might be the problem (although unlikely).

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself: Calling `EKEventStore`'s `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` method upon startup will open the prompt for calendar access, and also add my app to the device settings. Still curious why I failed to reproduce this on my iOS 6 iPad 3.

Comment: I just encounter same issue. your solution helps me.Thanks!

Comment: This will help for request Calendar access. but not for contact. Sometimes, contact privacy setting will miss some apps.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html
"Users are able to grant or deny access to contact data on a per-app basis. To request access to contact data, call the ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion function after calling the ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions function."